# Gson TypeToken in Scala

Tags: json, scala, gson

Am trying to parse JSON string which contains array of objects into Scala set. 
JSON string:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Orchestrator",
      "parent":"",
      "edit":false
   },
   {
      "name":"DBIntegrator",
      "parent":"Orchestrator",
      "edit":false
   }
]
```

Code to convert JSON string to Scala set:

```
val token: Type = new TypeToken[scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[ActorDefinition]](){}.getType
val newActorDefinitionList: scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[ActorDefinition] = new Gson().fromJson(json, token)
```

imports

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
```

ActorDefinition class:

```
class ActorDefinition(name: String, node: String, parent: String) {
    val actorName = name
    val parentActor = parent
    var canBeEdited: Boolean = false
}
```

When I execute the program I get exception as below :

```
exception:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I am new to this Scala and Gson, any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Could you try with a Java collection type instead of a Scala one? So e.g. a java.util.HashSet.

Comment: Yes, you seem to use Scala collections that have no default type adapters in Gson.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311813/gson-with-scala-scala-scala-collection-mutable-hashmap-vs-java-util-hashmap